# Set Theory Proof for Trignometry

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I solve whether $A$ is a subset of $B$, $B$ a subset of $A$, and whether either are proper subsets of each other for the following

$$A=\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid \cos x \in \mathbb{Z}\},\\ B=\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid \sin x \in \mathbb{Z}\} $$

Comment: You might note that the only integer values that $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ may take are $-1$, $0$ and $1$. Try to get more explicit characterizations of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I need help. I understand that all elements of A must be in B for A to be a subset of B. I also know that all elements of B must be in A for B to be a subset of A. And that A is a proper subset of B if every element of A is in B but there is at least one element in B that is not in A

Comment: Then you need to know *exactly* what are the elements of $A$ and $B$... The natural questions to ask yourself are: for what values of $x$ is $\cos(x)\in\{-1,0,1\}$ and for what values of $x$ is $\sin(x)\in\{-1,0,1\}$?

Comment: @user237642 : The other thing you need to understand in order to answer this is the sine and cosine functions.  What do you know about those?

Comment: not much. i am very lost.